# iOS UI Automation - how to find a row within a tableView

Tags: ios-ui-automation

I want to use UI Automation to look through a tableView and find the row that matches a certain label, and select that row. Is there a way to do this with UIAutomation?

Answer (score 2):

UIAutomation framework uses the UI element hierarchy to locate specific element on which you want to perform an automated action. Once you locate the table view from the UI element hierarchy of your app, you can call the function `.cells().firstWithName(The value of the name property of that cell).tap()`. This function will search all the rows of the table and tap on the first row with the name that matches the name string that you have passed as the argument. There is also a function `.withName(The value of the name property of that cell)` that returns an array of row objects all of which contain the name that matches the name string that you have passed as the argument.

p.s. The above mentioned functions only work with the name property.

Hope this helps!